# chain multiple calculations

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm doing the odin project calculator task on the final step it can take single calculations however I'm struggling to understand how to string together calculations/operators. Here is the criteria: Users should be able to string together several operations and get the right answer, with each pair of numbers being evaluated at a time. For example, 12 + 7 - 5 * 3 = should yield 42

```js
//global variables
let operator = '';
let previousValue = '';
let currentValue = '';

// DOM ELEMENTS
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  //storing all elements
  let clear = document.querySelector("#clear-btn");
  let equal = document.querySelector(".equal");
  let decimal = document.querySelector(".decimal");

  let number = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
  let operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");

  let previousScreen = document.querySelector(".previous");
  let currentScreen = document.querySelector(".current");

  // create event listeners for all the numbers
  number.forEach((number) => number.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    handleNumber(e.target.textContent);
    currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
  }));

  // create event listeners for all the operators 
  operatorButtons.forEach((op) => op.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    handleOperator(e.target.textContent)
    previousScreen.textContent = previousValue + " " + operator;
    currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
  }));
  //clear button
  clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
    previousValue = '';
    currentValue = '';
    operator = '';
    previousScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
  })

  //calculate event listener goes here
  equal.addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (currentValue != '' && previousValue != '') {
      calculate()
      previousScreen.textContent = '';
      if (previousValue, length <= 5) {
        currentScreen.textContent = previousValue;
      } else(
        currentScreen.textContent = previousValue.slice(0, 5) + "..."
      )
    }
  })
})

//limits length of current value to 5 digits
function handleNumber(num) {
  if (currentValue.length <= 5) {
    currentValue += num;
  }
}
//updates the operator variable and transfers the current value to the previous value, preparing the calculator for the next input.
function handleOperator(op) {
  operator = op;
  previousValue = currentValue;
  currentValue = '';
}

//calculation function
function calculate() {
  previousValue = Number(previousValue);
  currentValue = Number(currentValue);
  //operator logic
  if (operator === "+") {
    previousValue += currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "-") {
    previousValue -= currentValue;
  } else if (operator === "/") {
    previousValue /= currentValue;
  } else {
    previousValue *= currentValue
  }
  //rounds numbers 
  previousValue = roundNumber(previousValue);
  //checking answers in console first
  // console.log(previousValue);
};

//function for rounding the answer
function roundNumber(num) {
  return Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<!-- black-border -->

<div class="calculator">
  <div class="first-row">
    <div id="display">
      <div class="previous"></div>
      <div class="current"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="clear-btn" class="btn">C</button>
  </div>
  <div class="other-rows">
    <button class="btn number">7</button>
    <button class="btn number">8</button>
    <button class="btn number">9</button>
    <button class="btn operator divide">/</button>
  </div>
  <div class="other-rows">
    <button class="btn number">4</button>
    <button class="btn number">5</button>
    <button class="btn number">6</button>
    <button class="btn operator">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="other-rows">
    <button class="btn number">1</button>
    <button class="btn number">2</button>
    <button class="btn number">3</button>
    <button class="btn operator">-</button>
  </div>
  <div class="other-rows">
    <button class="btn number">0</button>
    <button class="btn decimal">.</button>
    <button class="btn equal">=</button>
    <button class="btn operator">+</button>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself the right questions, in this case the most important one might be:

- When do you want something to happen?

---

```
12 + 7 - 5 * 3
```

Normally the result of that would be **4**, not **42**:

```
(12 + 7) - (5 * 3) = 4
```

You explicitly stated that you want 42, so it's actually more like:

```
(((12 + 7) - 5) * 3) = 42
```

In other words, the calculations that need to happen are:

```
12 + 7 = 19
19 - 5 = 14
14 * 3 = 42
```

As you see, the "chain of calculations" is broken up into pairs of "intermediate result" and "next number". It's always only 2 numbers.

Going back to our question:
When do you want to calculate these intermediate results?
Also, is the intermediate result the "previous value" or the "current value"?